# How can I migrate my JSF 1.2 project from WAS 7 to 9

Tags: jsf, websphere, server-application

Good afternoon, I have a project done in JSF version 1.2 which is on a WebSphere Application Server 7 server but I want to deploy it on a WebSphere Application Server 9. What points should I take into account so that everything goes well.
My project has the following libraries:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-commons-3.1.jar
asm-tree-3.1.jar
aspectjtools-1.6.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-collections-2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
DynamicJasper-4.0.3.jar
FlexiCoreProvider-1.7p2.signed.jar
freemarker-2.3.16.jar
hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar
IntegraUtil.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
jasperreports-5.0.0.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-facelets.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jsf-tlds.jar
jstl.jar
jxl-2.6.10.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
ognl-3.0.1.jar
ojdbc6.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
richfaces-api-3.3.2.SR1.jar
richfaces-impl-3.3.2.SR1.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.2.SR1.jar
standard.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

Your recommendations would be helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebSphere Application server you have the option to switch the implementation of JSF at the application server level to Sun Reference Implementation 1.2 or My Faces 2.0. [How to set the JSF version](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html). I think this is a server level settings and applies to all the applications running there. You may also have to change the class loading order to parent last

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes that were introduced in the area of JSF. I would recommend running the WebSphere migration tools against your application so it can flag issues for JSF and other technologies.

You can run the binary scanner against your .war/.ear files: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries

If you're using Eclipse, you can run the source scanner against your Eclipse project: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit